# Ideals of non-Noetherian Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian

Example 1 :

If $L= \bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty S_i$, where $S_i$ is simple Lie algebra, then $L$ is non-Noetherian Lie algebra.

Since every ideal $A$ of $L$ has the property $A^2=[A, A]=A$, then every ideal $S_i$ is semi-prime.

Since $L$ is the only prime ideal of itself, then $r(S_i)=L$.

Is this true??

> Notions:-
> A Lie algebra $L$ satisfy the maximal condition for ideals, if for each , ascending chain $H_{1} \subseteq H_{2} \subseteq \ldots $ an index $m$ exists such that $H_{i}=H_{k}$ if $m<i$, $m<k.$ We say in short: $ L\in{\rm Max}-\triangleleft$ (Noetherian Lie algebra).

> An ideal $Q$ of $L$ is called semi-prime if $H^2 \subseteq Q$ with $H$ an ideal of $L$ implies $H\subseteq Q$.

> $r(H)$ denote the intersection of all the prime ideals of $L$ containing $H$.

Comment: Do you mean "then every ideal $A$ is semi-prime"? Of course the $S_i$ in particular are semi-prime too, but a general ideal $A$ is of the form $\bigoplus_{i \in I} S_i$ for some subset $I \subseteq \mathbb N$.

Comment: And I made that mistake before, but $L$ is *not* the only prime ideal of $L$. The others are the $\bigoplus_{i\in I}S_i$ for sets $I$ which are complements of singletons, i.e. $I= \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}, \mathbb{N} \setminus \{2\}, ...$, i.e. the maximal proper ideals. It follows in particular that $r(S_i)=S_i$.

Comment: Do these maximal ideals exist really!! I think that because $N$ is infinite, then every proper ideal $A$ has another proper ideal $B$ contains $A$, hence $A$ can't be maximal, thus $A$ can't be prime, but I realize that this ideal is not true. The ideals with a complement of singletons as index sets are maximal.

Comment: I would have expected that $L$ is by convention not a prime ideal?

Comment: Prime ideals in Lie algebra need not be proper ideals.